# Another "conversion from type DBNull to type Date not valid" issue

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, dbnull

I have looked in other threads with this similar issue but haven't found my answer yet.

The code selects items from a `DataGridView` and places them into textboxes for easy reading. I get this error if once of the dates hasnt been completed. The date is nullable in SQL...

Here is my code... trying to deal with it.

```
If Not DataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells(9).Value() Is Nothing Then
    txtduetoend.Text = CType(DataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells(9).Value(), DateTime).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
End If
```

It's not working..

Any ideas?

Comment: `Value` is a property so don't append `()` which is for methods only. That's just confusing.

Comment: When getting the date from database check for database null value and set the property in the data class to some default value if so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a variable because it's more readable and less error-prone:

```
Dim obj = DataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells(9).Value
Dim dueToEnd As Date? = Nothing
If obj IsNot Nothing AndAlso Not DBNull.Value.Equals(obj) Then dueToEnd = CType(obj, Date?)
If dueToEnd.HasValue Then
    txtduetoend.Text = dueToEnd.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
End If
```

Comment: That tells me "specified cast is not valid"

Comment: @PaulBedford: what type is it?

Comment: That update has fixed it.. thanks so much! I realise now looking at your code what was wrong.